# The location property of CLLocationManager can be nil, which however is not an optional variable

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Swift, and notice the definition of the location property of CLLocationManager:
[image]

Note in Swift, it is defined as **CLLocation!**. How ever, it is said that

> The value of this property is **nil** if ...

Is there any problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CLLocation!` variable *is* an optional, but it is just a implicitly unwrapped one. As [The Swift Programming Language: The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-XID_0) says:

> [Optionals] indicate that a constant or variable is allowed to have “no value”. Optionals can be checked with an if statement to see if a value exists, and can be conditionally unwrapped with optional binding to access the optional’s value if it does exist.
>
> Sometimes it is clear from a program’s structure that an optional will always have a value, after that value is first set. In these cases, it is useful to remove the need to check and unwrap the optional’s value every time it is accessed, because it can be safely assumed to have a value all of the time.
>
> These kinds of optionals are defined as implicitly unwrapped optionals. You write an implicitly unwrapped optional by placing an exclamation mark (`String!`) rather than a question mark (`String?`) after the type that you want to make optional.

So, `location` is an optional, but you don't have to explicitly unwrap it every time you use it because it is an implicitly unwrapped for you.